# Open Tridion Publish Queue with Parameters

Tags: cme

I built a Tridion Custom Page that has a link to open the Tridion Publish Queue with a URL like this, http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/PublishQueue/PublishQueue.aspx#popup=UID_314

Is it possible to pass other parameters into the URL to apply filters, such as the username, state or date/time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it's possible to pass parameters but they will just be ignored.

So to do what you are asking, you'd need to write an extension to the dialog that reads those parameters and acts on them.

Comment: "Technically it's possible to pass parameters but they will just be ignored." In case anyone anywhere ever wondered: you've just self-identified as an engineer. :-)

Comment: I tried to just answer 'No' but it insisted I wrote more :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible if you are building a custom page where you are providing the parameters. The code behind file can construct the PublishTransactionsFilterData class which provides constructor for what you can filter in the transactions. You can use GetSystemWideListXml that returns an XML which has the transaction detail like publish transaction ID and you can make another coreservice read call to get the PublishTransactionData object for the transaction ID. this can pretty much provide what yu are looking for.

Another option is to convert the input parameters as parameters for stored proc that can query the PUBLISH_TRANSACTION table holding all the required data. You can look at the table definition for what can be queried against. this is faster than the core service based since you are querying the underlying data directly. problem is when tridion updates the tridion schemas and tables can break your stored proc and hence is not advisable to  use DB querying mechanism.